# Mail.app Automator/Sript action for suspicious emails

Tags: mail.app, applescript, automator

I am getting fed up with the surprisingly professional looking SCAMS arriving in my Inbox.

I wanted to create an Automator action which would tell me who is the actual sender by looking up the IP it came from.

Normally if I get suspicious I would:

1-Show full header of the email (using All Headers)

2-Find and Look up the Originating IP address using [who is](http://whois.net/)

3- Decide based on actual IP location and owner what to do.

--This IP originates in Italy? So it is safe to say that AMEX would not use a server in Italy to send me such email.

**I can use some help how to Automate the Steps 1 and 2 (and the 2.1) in mail.**

Here are the samples;
The Email
[image: the scam email]

The Header

[image: the email header]

The sample of the content of the html file

[image: html content]

I found this [Can I make Mail.app search Received: headers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/can-i-make-mail-app-search-received-headers) which is along the way, but it does not answer the question.

PS:
I know I could just delete it and go on with life, but:
I would miss helping innocent people, informing them that their server was hacked and being used by Criminals, as I already did so successfully few times, helping to shut them down.
Once it was a Wells Fago web site on a server of a travel operator in Russia.
Another time it was a Visa website on a Restaurant server in Iceland. And now this one.

**UPDATE..UPDATE...UPDATE...**

I found this that comes close to what I want, but would need some tweaking. Unfortunately, it is way beyond my scripting ability so any help is appreciated:

```
modified May 27, 2003 by M. Kluskens

? parse out all Received headers (important if mail passes through several trusted email servers)
? parse out the IP address from Eudora Internet mail Server headers (EIMS)
? added trusted IP address list
*)

on perform_mail_action(info)

(* Prompt levels: 0=no dialog boxes, 1=show dialog boxes when Spam is found, 2=show all dialog boxes, 3 =debug/verbose *)
set ShowPrompts to 0

-- list of trusted IP addresses not to look up
set TrustedIPlist to {"127.0.0.1", "203.97.196.98", "219.88.68.80"}

set BlackListsToCheck to {"bl.spamcop.net", "relays.osirusoft.com", "relays.ordb.org", "blackholes.wirehub.net", "list.dsbl.org", "dynablock.wirehub.net", "dialups.visi.com"}

(* Perform a nslookup against various RBL blacklists as DNS queries by executing the following: *)
(* nslookup IP4.IP3.IP2.IP1.[blacklist], a result of 127.0.0.2 is ususlly indicative of a positive match *)
(* Some Blacklists: bl.spamcop.net, relays.ordb.org, orbs.dorkslayers.com, dev.null.dk, relays.visi.com
relays.osirusoft.com (a.k.a. SPEWS uses 127.0.0.4 as a positive match) *)

tell application "Mail"
(* Process messages in the IN Box *)

set NewMail to |SelectedMessages| of info
repeat with CurrentMessage in NewMail
set RawSource to source of CurrentMessage
-- separate out different headers to check more than just the first [] pair
set HeaderName to "Start" as string
set ResolvedIP to "Cleared" as string
set loopCount to 1
-- checking complete when Subject, Date, From, or To header encountered
repeat until (HeaderName = "Subject:" or HeaderName = "Date:" or HeaderName = "From:" or HeaderName = "To:")
set Header to paragraph loopCount of RawSource
set Headerstart to the (offset of ":" in Header)
if (Headerstart > 0) then
set HeaderName to (characters 1 thru Headerstart of Header) as string
-- append the rest of the header text to the header (plus any uninteresting headers)
repeat
set Header2 to paragraph (loopCount + 1) of RawSource
set HeaderStart2 to the (offset of ":" in Header2)
if (HeaderStart2 ? 0) then
set HeaderName2 to (characters 1 thru HeaderStart2 of Header2) as string
if (HeaderName2 = "Received:" or HeaderName2 = "Subject:" or HeaderName2 = "Date:" or HeaderName2 = "From:" or HeaderName2 = "To:") then exit repeat
end if
set loopCount to loopCount + 1
set Header to (Header & Header2)
end repeat

if (HeaderName = "Received:") then
(* Locate the Originating IP Address in the raw E-Mail header *)
-- Sendmail and others
set start to the (offset of "[" in Header) + 1
set finish to the (offset of "]" in Header) - 1
-- Eudora Internet Mail Server
if (start = 1 or finish = -1) then
set start to the (offset of "(" in Header) + 1
set finish to the (offset of ")" in Header) - 1
end if

if (start < finish) then

set IPAddress to (characters start thru finish of Header) as string
if (ShowPrompts > 2) then
display dialog " Relay's IP " & IPAddress
end if

if (IPAddress is not in TrustedIPlist) then
(* Parse the IPAddress text into its IP1.IP2.IP3.IP4 fields, starting from the end IP4 to IP1 *)
copy text (((length of IPAddress) + 2) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) thru (length of IPAddress) of IPAddress to IP4
copy text 1 thru ((length of IPAddress) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) of IPAddress to IPAddress

copy text (((length of IPAddress) + 1) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) thru (length of IPAddress) of IPAddress to IP3
copy text 1 thru ((length of IPAddress) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) of IPAddress to IPAddress

copy text (((length of IPAddress) + 1) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) thru (length of IPAddress) of IPAddress to IP2
copy text 1 thru ((length of IPAddress) - ((offset of "." in (reverse of characters of IPAddress) as string))) of IPAddress to IP1

repeat with BlackList in BlackListsToCheck
set LookUpResult to do shell script ("nslookup " & IP4 & IP3 & IP2 & "." & IP1 & "." & BlackList)

(* Parse the tail end of the last line looking for a match *)

set resultoffset to (((length of LookUpResult) + 1) - (offset of ":" in (((reverse of characters of LookUpResult)) as string)))
copy text (resultoffset + 3) thru (resultoffset + 10) of LookUpResult to ResolvedIP

if ResolvedIP = "127.0.0." then
set ResolvedIP to "SPAM!!!" as string
else
set ResolvedIP to "Cleared" as string
end if

if (ResolvedIP = "SPAM!!!") then exit repeat
end repeat
end if -- ( IPAddress is not is TrustedIPlist)
end if -- ( start < finish )
end if -- ( Headername = "Received:" )
end if -- ( Headerstart > 0 )
set loopCount to loopCount + 1
if (ResolvedIP = "SPAM!!!") then exit repeat
end repeat -- until

(* If it was listed in the RBL Move message to Junk folder and mark as Junk mail *)
if (ResolvedIP = "SPAM!!!") then
if (ShowPrompts > 0) then
display dialog "Found SPAM listed on " & BlackList & "
Move Message to Junk Mail" & "

From: " & (sender of CurrentMessage) & "

Subject: " & (subject of CurrentMessage)
end if

set is junk mail of CurrentMessage to true
-- change this line to match your junk/spam mailbox
set mailbox of CurrentMessage to mailbox "Junk"

else
if (ShowPrompts > 1) then
display dialog ResolvedIP & " Sender's IP " & IP1 & IP2 & IP3 & "." & IP4 & "

From: " & (sender of CurrentMessage) & "

Subject: " & (subject of CurrentMessage)
end if
end if

end repeat
end tell
end perform_mail_action
[/code]
```

Comment: I've voted your question up as you're willing to help innocent people. And I'd like to know the answer myself too. - Header shows Hotmail.com <- AMEX would not use that either NOR using such a html form :)

Comment: The difficult part was to open or not the html attachment, since it could contain an automated action that would harm me. Finally, I figured it out to use the Quick Look which does not open the file on my computer. But knowing where the IP is originating from is usually enough for me.

Comment: Open it using NotePad++ or something similar, and it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that Automator by itself has enough vocabulary to perform this task, but with a little Applescript you can get there.

If you've upgraded to Mavericks you can use a [library to add ICU regular expressions](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=168797#p168797) to your script, but awk, sed, and Perl give you plenty of parsing power without them.

I run Applescript on my system using FastScripts or Keyboard Maestro but an Automator service should work as well.

Note that this script is not a complete answer to your problem but provides most of the tools you need solve it.

-ccs

```
try

    set lookUpAgent to "http://www.lookip.net/whois/"

    tell application "Mail"
        set selMsgList to selection
        if selMsgList ≠ {} then
            set selMsg to item 1 of selMsgList
            tell selMsg
                set headerText to all headers
            end tell
        else
            error "No messages were selected!"
        end if
    end tell

    # Parse the header-text to your heart's content.
    # A simple example:
    set parsedText to do shell script "egrep -i ^received: <<< " & quoted form of headerText

    # Let's say the IP address you parse out is:
    set ipAdrs to "17.172.224.47"

    set lookUpUrl to lookUpAgent & ipAdrs

    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        make new document with properties {URL:lookUpUrl}
    end tell

on error e number n
    set e to e & return & return & "Num: " & n
    tell me to set dDlg to display dialog e with title ¬
        "ERROR!" buttons {"Cancel", "Copy", "OK"} default button "OK"
    if button returned of dDlg = "Copy" then set the clipboard to e
end try
```